# Question about bilinear form

Tags: bilinear-form

Prove that every bilinear form $f:\mathbb R^n \times \mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R$ has a basis $\{v_1,\ldots,v_n\} \subset \mathbb R^n$ such that $f(v_i,v_j)=-f(v_j,v_i)$ for every $i\neq j$.

I have no idea how to start thinking about this one. Should I actually "build" the required basis or what? Any ideas ?

thanks

Comment: I think this is not true, you can consider any simmetric bilinear form as a counterexample.

Comment: @DiegoMath But that's not a counterexample, take any basis you like for $\mathbb{R}$ and the condition is satisfied because it is vacuous ($f(v_i,v_j) = -f(v_j, v_i)$ for all $i \ne j,\ i,j\in\{1\}$).

Comment: Try this counterexample: $f:\mathbb{R^n}\times\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R}$, defined by $f(x,y)=\langle x,y\rangle$. This is a bilinear form such that $f(x,y)=f(y,x)$, $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R^n}$.

Comment: @DiegoMath I was pointing out that in your original counterexample the the condition was fine as there was only 1 dimension and so there is no distinct pair $i,j$ both in $\{1\}$ for which anything would need to hold.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15243/discussion-between-alex-j-best-and-diegomath).

Comment: Where does this question actually come from?

Comment: Given any bilinear form $f$, consider its symmetric part

$$f_{sym} :  \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \ni (u,v) \quad\mapsto\quad
f_{sym}(u,v) = \frac12 [ f(u,v) + f(v,u) ] \in \mathbb{R}$$

Pick an arbitrary basis $\big\{\;u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_n\;\big\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and define the matrix $A = (A_{ij})$:

$$A_{ij} = f_{sym}( u_i, u_j ),\quad 1 \le i, j \le n$$

$A$ is a real symmetric matrix and hence diagonalizable through orthogonal matrices.  
i.e. there exists $O = (O_{ij}) \in O(n)$ such that $D = OAO^{-1} = OAO^T$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: Construct a new basis $\big\{\;v_1, v_2,\ldots,v_n\;\big\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^n$:

$$v_i = \sum_{j=1}^n O_{ij} u_j,\quad i = 1,2,\ldots, n$$

With respect to this basis, we have

$$f_{sym}( v_i, v_j ) = f_{sym}\left( \sum_{i'=1}^n O_{ii'} u_{i'}, \sum_{j'=1}^n O_{jj'} u_{j'} \right) = (OAO^T)_{ij} = D_{ij}
$$
When $i \ne j$, $D_{ij} = 0$ and hence $f_{sym}( v_i, v_j ) = 0 \iff f(v_i,v_j) = - f(v_j,v_i)$.